# How to set Environment variable in AWS EMR using SSM to be used by pyspark scripts

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am using emr-6.12.0 and trying to set environment varibles which are stored in secret manager in bootstrap.sh file.

```
SECRET_NAME="/myapp/dev/secrets"
SECRETS_JSON=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id $SECRET_NAME --query SecretString --output text)

# Parse the secrets and set them as environment variables
for key in $(echo "$SECRETS_JSON" | jq -r "keys[]"); do
  value=$(echo "$SECRETS_JSON" | jq -r ".$key // empty" | sed 's/"/\\"/g')
  echo "$value"
  if [ ! -z "$value" ]; then
    export "$key"="$value"
  fi
done
```

I am able to see these values in log.

but when I try to access these variables from my pyspark script, I am not able to get these env variables.

```
os.environ.get("POSTGRES_URL") // Returns None

for key, value in os.environ.items():
    self.logger.info(f"{key}: {value}") // not able to see my env variables
```

As I am new to EMR and spark, please help me to know how can I set my env variables from SSM to EMR.

Comment: Which --deploy-mode you are using, client or cluster?

Comment: Also, what process the env variables are for, the driver or executors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve secrets from amazon secret manager in your python application, you'll need to follow the following steps:

```
pip install aws-secretsmanager-caching
```

After that, in your app.py, you'll have something like this:

```
import botocore 
import botocore.session 
from aws_secretsmanager_caching import SecretCache, SecretCacheConfig 

client = botocore.session.get_session().create_client('secretsmanager')
cache_config = SecretCacheConfig()
cache = SecretCache( config = cache_config, client = client)

secret = cache.get_secret_string('mysecret')
```

NB: You must have the following:

- Python 3.6 or later.
- botocore 1.12 or higher
- setuptools_scm 3.2 or higher

Required permission:

- secretsmanager:DescribeSecret
- secretsmanager:GetSecretValue

Official [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/retrieving-secrets_cache-python.html)

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to set it in your `conf/spark-defaults.conf` file or if you don't wana edit global conf files use it via `spark submit --conf spark.executorEnv.FOO=bar --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.FOO=bar`

See docs for more details:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#environment-variables